# Почему не запускается проект django в контенере?

Tags: django, docker

Пытаюсь завернуть учебный проект с БД Sqlite в контенер (пока что без compose) но выходит ошибка.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? image создается, контенер запускается, все ок, но при з переходе на страницу сайта выходит нижеприведенная ошибка:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR app
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY ./req.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r req.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
RUN python manage.py makemigrations
RUN python manage.py migrate
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

**settings.py:**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]', '0.0.0.0']
```

**запуск контенера:**

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 --rm --name go test
```

**Ошибка:**

> Не удается получить доступ к сайтуВеб-страница по адресу 0.0.0.0:8000,
> возможно, временно недоступна или постоянно перемещена по новому
> адресу. ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID

Answer (score 0):

Нашел проблему - открывать нужно было не 0.0.0.0:8000 а 127.0.0.1

Осталось теперь только понять почему такое поведение)

Comment: Потому что 0.0.0.0 не является настоящим адресом, а для сервера он всего лишь является указанием прослушивать все доступные сетевые интерфейсы (в том числе 127.0.0.1)